# vscode doesn't change to single-quote in vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm write `Vue` applications in `vscode` and I using `prettier`.

I added single quote rule to `tslint.json`:

```
"quotemark": [true, "single"]
```

Also I add singleQuote to `settings.json`:

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

But when I format my code in the vue file, `vscode` doesn't change from double quotes to single quotes. but it's works in ts file.

App.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Any ideas why? and what I can do?

Comment: Does it work in other files? For example .ts files?

Comment: yes. it works in ts files.